# Mysql-nodejs nested queries

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

It says that cannot read property `authorid` undefined in socket.broadcast line.

```
setInterval(function(){
    db.query("select * from `notifications`", function(err, rows){
        if (rows.length>temp){

            for (var i=temp; i<rows.length; i++){
                console.log('sending room post', rows[i].authorid);
                db.query("select `name` from `users` where `id`=?", [rows[i].authorid ], function(err, name){
                    name=name[0].name;
                    socket.broadcast.to(rows[i].authorid).emit('new notification', {
                        authorname:name,
                        dpid:rows[i].followid,
                        read:rows[i].read,
                        type:rows[i].type,
                        followstatus:1
                    }); 
                });


            }
            temp=rows.length;
        }
    })
}, 3000);
```

Comment: What does the console.log outputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the value of `i` is `rows.length` when using the socket.

You can fix this by creating a function to which you send the current row or send the `index` and use `rows[index]`:

```
setInterval(function() {
    db.query("select * from `notifications`", function(err, rows) {

        // You access the values of the current row
        // row.authorid
        // ...
        var broadcast = function(row) {
            console.log('sending room post', row.authorid);
            db.query("select `name` from `users` where `id`=?", [row.authorid], function(err, name) {
                name=name[0].name;
                socket.broadcast.to(row.authorid).emit('new notification', {
                    authorname:   name,
                    dpid:         row.followid,
                    read:         row.read,
                    type:         row.type,
                    followstatus: 1
                }); 
            });
        };

        if (rows.length>temp) {
            for (var i=temp; i<rows.length; i++) {
                broadcast(rows[i]);
            }
            temp=rows.length;
        }
    })
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. But I can't seem to understand why i is being used by socket?

Comment: `i` was used by `socket` when you were calling `socket.broadcast.to(rows[i].authorid)`. The value of `i` was higher than the length of rows so there was no element in `rows[i]`

Comment: Oh is it because the query is asynchronous?

Comment: For example having a list with 3 elements. rows[author_1, author_2, author_3]. You use this list in a `for` loop. You might think that when you first call `socket.broadcast.to..` the value of `i` is `0` and you are using `rows[0] => meaning author_1`. Well this is wrong. You are actually accessing `rows[3]` which doesn't exist. And  you already know the reason => asynchronous calls